# @ExceptionHandler and validation errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am wondering how to pass information to the exception handler.  Say for example I doing validation. Whit @Valid. I can catch that specific exception but that does not tell me if was the first name or last name of the person that was wrong.

Maybe a custom exception with a error field attribute. If I do that is how to I through it? 
@Valid have already thrown an exception if validation fails.

Can i check the bindingresult for error and throw my custom exception? How do solve this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@Valid Person person) {
    System.out.println(person);
    System.out.println(person2);

    return "home";
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public List<FailureResult> handleException
    (Exception re, HttpServletResponse response) {

    FailureResult failureResult = new FailureResult();
    failureResult.setName("name");
            //wich feild failed the validation?


    List<FailureResult> r = new ArrayList<FailureResult>();
    r.add(failureResult);

    return r;
}
```